# Proper index for between clause

Tags: mysql, indexing

What would be the proper index on a table where I will be running a query like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date1_col AND date2_col
```

Is an index on `date1_col` sufficient or I must index both columns, or a complex index is needed?

Additionally, will `NOW()` be calculated for every row? Would it be better to provide it as a literal when constructing the query?

Comment: You will need the indexes on both the dates, using the between you are asking mysql to do the comparison as `date1_col > = now() and date2_col <= now()`, also if the date columns are stored as `date` datatype then use `curdate()` instead of `now()` and yes now() is calculated at that point in time when the query is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BETWEEN date_1 AND date_2` cannot be optimized.  However, the Optimizer will pick between these at runtime:

```
INDEX(date_1, date_2) if the date is near the end of the date_1 values, or
INDEX(date_2, date_1) if the date is near the start of that index.
```

So, have both of those indexes.  At worst, the query will have to scan nearly half the table.

So, why not use just the 1-column versions?  Let's dissect things a little more...  An index is a B+Tree ordered according the column(s) specified.  Such a tree can efficiently be scanned linearly (from start to date or date to end, depending on which index), but after that, it needs to check the other of date_1/2.

If you have just `INDEX(date_1)`, then it must reach into the BTree where the data resides to get `date_2` to check it.

If, on the other hand, you are using `INDEX(date_1, date_2)`, then the value is right there, and the "Attached condition" can more quickly be tested.  In a non-JSON `EXPLAIN`, that is indicated by "Using index condition" in the Extra column.  This is "ICP".

I think (but am not sure) that using *only* the 2-column indexes would be better.

Note:  ICP was added in 5.6.10, I think.  So it depends on how old your version is.

A "covering" index is one that includes *all* columns mentioned in the `SELECT`.  This is even better, but it is somewhat limited because changing `SELECT user` to `SELECT user, foo` makes these no longer "covering":

```
INDEX(date_1, date_2, user)
INDEX(date_2, date_1, user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's add 4 indexes and use `EXPLAIN`:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN date_1 AND date_2;
```

and look at the result:

```
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "table": {
            "table_name": "user",
            "access_type": "range",
            "possible_keys": [
                "idx_date_1_date_2",
                "idx_date_1",
                "idx_date_2",
                "idx_date_2_date_1"
            ],
            "key": "idx_date_2",
            "used_key_parts": [
                "date_2"
            ],
            "key_length": "5",
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100,
            "attached_condition": "(<cache>(now()) between `portalintl_db`.`user`.`date_1` and `portalintl_db`.`user`.`date_2`)"
        }
    }
}
```

At first, `now()` is marked with the `<cache>` mark. It means that `NOW()` will be calculated only once.

At second, `idx_date_2` have been used for the query. So you need only one index on the `date_2` column. Also, `idx_date_2_date_1` will works too, but MySQL will use only `date_2` part.

If want more details about `EXPLAIN` output, feel free to read documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-extended.html

Comment: When you have `INDEX(a,b)` it is almost always a waste to also have `INDEX(a)`.